# My sql statement has two parts attached with 'union all'. I want the second part to exceecute only when some condition is true

Tags: mysql, sql-server, db2, union

my query is too big to paste here and refers to at least 15 tables, so i am pasting a small example to explain my problem

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country 
FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany'
ORDER BY City;
```

i want the union all part of query to execute only when some condition is true ( that comes from the UI in a parameter), e.g. `boolean combo=true`.

Thanks

Comment: Is this SQL Server, MySql or DB2? Can't be all of them

Comment: You can add a condition to your second where clauses: and 1=@x. If you pass 0, the second query should return quickly with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country 
FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany'
AND   @Combo = true
ORDER BY City;
```

It still runs the second part of the union however will only return records if @Combo is true. Saves lots of IF THEN ELSE statements. Also helps if you have many queries in the union as each query can have it's own @Combo variable.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it worked. Same was suggested by Tim3880 in comments above and it worked...

Comment: No probs. I'm new to stack exchange and often by the time I've finished an answer someone else has already suggested it. Need to work faster!